# Different favicon in each browser tab in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web, favicon

We have a custom session mechanism in our application, that allows user to have different session (e.g., different credentials) in each browser tab, **even if URLs are the same**. This mechanism works great in all major browsers including IE (v11).

**The problem**

We want to supply each browser tab with different favicon (with different color) to indicate which tab belongs to which session. To do that, we set different favicon URL depending on session using

```
<link rel='icon' href='url_to_favicon_session_id' type='image/ico'/>
```

It works great in Firefox and Chrome, however IE seems to share favicon between all tabs pointing at the same URL (icon is the same in each tab, order of loading determinates favicon visible in each tab).

**The question**

Can we force IE somehow to not share favicons across browser tabs with the same URLs?

Note, changing URL is not an option here.

**Minimal Working Example**

Below full code snippet to reproduce problem (put it on a webserver to run in IE with HTML5 support; Open this file in many tabs of the same browser).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var icons = [
                "http://google.com/images/google_favicon_128.png",
                "https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico",
                "https://www.microsoft.com/favicon.ico?v2",
                "https://s.yimg.com/rz/l/favicon.ico",
                "http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico",
            ];

            var idx = localStorage["favicon"];
            if (idx === undefined) {
                idx = 0;
            } else {
                idx = parseInt(idx);
            }

            localStorage["favicon"] = (idx + 1) % icons.length;

            var link = document.createElement('link');
            link.type = 'image/x-icon';
            link.rel = 'icon';
            link.href = icons[idx];
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Open this page in multiple tabs. Favicon should be different in each tab.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the example, the favicon tag is generated through JavaScript. Is that also the case in the real application? If so, I can imagine that IE loads favicon from its cache (based on the url) and won't reload it when the JavaScript kicks in. In that case, you might try to render it server side in the initial page content.

Comment: No, in real application favicon is embedded in HTML code. However it does not matter for IE *how* the favicon is included in the page, but what is the *page's* URL. Moreover it's not a caching issue, since  (1) if you load the code I provided in two different URLs it works as expected, (2) even if HTML is cached, the script would load different favicon URL, so favicon file caching is not relevant here.

Comment: A work around may be to append a dummy unique parameter to the page URL for each session (e.g. http://yoursite.com/page?id=<unique id>). This will force IE11 to load a different favicon on each tab.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, IE, along with almost all other browsers, uses a cache mechanism separate from the cache of the page to prevent constant retrieval of favicons. This means that changes to the favicon can be unpredictable unless the url is changed and the cache for the domain cleared. The only reliable way I can see around this is to add a unique id to identify the tab for each session forcing IE to cache each sessions's icon separately.

You can try a GET variable (i.e. yoursite.com/page?sessionid), however, in my experience, IE still cache's the favicon across page in the same domain regardless of GET variable. In fact, [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that you can use the link tag to get different pages to have different favicon's, however, I often find that IE's favicon cache won't update even if you change the link tag without clearing the cache. Also, IE won't display a favicon at all if you have all caching turned off. And, it appears that in some versions of IE, the link tag doesn't take precedence over whatever favicon is at the default location either.

I have had some success with using a routing script to get requests to the right page and then appending the sessionid as part of the path (ie. yoursite.com/page/sessionid), however. This requires a bit of extra work in your routing script to ignore the sessionid but it is the only thing, in my experience, that worked simi-reliably to get IE to recognize different favicon's for different sessions.

Comment: The way with session id in URL and routing script is actually a way how our session mechanism works. However the URL of the page visible to the user (in the location bar) is spoofed using history API. We do not want the user to see the session id or copy it somewhere (note: this is not really a security concern in our case, rather a usability one). Asking this question I had actually hope that some IE insider guy would reveal us some other factor than URL that influences displayed favicon or ensure us that factor like this does not exist.

Comment: I see. I have done as much research as I can to try and find other factors, but it just seems to be a very aggressive url based cache. Kind of odd that IE is so worried about not transferring the favicon on each request that they make such an aggressive cache for them yet continue to send hundreds of unnecessary bytes in the Accept header and other places.